# iTextSharp writer.AddDirectImageSimple throws exception

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext

What could be the problem for writer to throw an error, when the code seems correct?  Image also exists.

```
var img2 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\2.bmp");

writer.AddDirectImageSimple(img2);

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddDirectImageSimple(Image image, PdfIndirectReference fixedRef)
at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.AddDirectImageSimple(Image image)
```

Comment: is the writer open? can you share the lines that creates the writer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you add an image to a PDF. The method `AddDirectImageSimple` is to be usd by specialists only.

What is your purpose when you use that method? If you want to add an `Image` to the document, you should use:

```
document.Add(img2);
```